# What kind of security do authenticator apps use to protect the seed?

Tags: encryption, authentication, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I'm not 100% sure if this question is supposed to be here or in Cryptography forum, but I'll try anyway.

I would like to have some idea as to how software authenticator apps such as Google Authenticator, Duo, Okta, etc store the secret (i.e., seed) for TOTP and HOTP authentication. Since they all can work offline, it means the seeds are stored somewhere on the client device. Are they encrypted at all? Or there is no need to protect them since the ownership of the device itself is the only requirement for such OTP authentication?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/ might be a better option for your question, despite it not being off-topic for superuser (as far as I know). If you don't get any reply here soon you could go there, however, do not duplicate your question (make sure it is only on one stackexchange site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They rely on security provided by the device.

Android and iOS have much stricter security model than desktop computers. Each app has its private storage that is inaccessible for others. Under normal circumstances it's enough to store the seed in this storage and don't add any means to extract it to the app. This storage should also be marked as non-backupable because that would allow for extraction of seeds or would store them in storage that is not considered secure enough (3rd party cloud).

This private storage can be accessed if device is rooted or jailbroken, so using such device as TOTP token is not secure.

Comment: It depends heavily on the app. Some of them use a separate encryption password, or a key stored in the Android keystore (andOTP).